# Azure BICEP deploy if doesn't already exist

Tags: azure, infrastructure-as-code, azure-bicep

I'm not sure if this is possible, but what I'm trying to do is create a virtual network from one `virtualNetwork.main.bicep` file and then create a subnet from another `subnet.main.bicep` within the virtual network. Now I can do this, but the problem I have is if I rerun the virtual network `virtualNetwork.main.bicep` it will remove any subnets that have been created by the `subnet.main.bicep` file

I know I can just add all subnets to the `virtualNetwork.main.bicep` but the idea is that I can hand over the creation of subnets to other people whilst maintaining a global networking configuration.

So is there any way that I can only stop the virtual network file from deleting what's already there?

Hope this makes sense.

Cheers

Comment: You could get the existing VNET configuration and merge the subnets properties but then your tempalte can become really complicated. Ig you use az cli to create the vnet, it will be easier. you can create a vnet, create some subnets then if you rerun the az cli script it wont delete existing subnets.

Answer (score 1):

Checking to see if a resource already exists is an [ask](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/4023) in Bicep that isn't yet implemented.

Further, you're looking at creating a virtual network from multiple modules and I fear you're going to be disappointed there as well, as that's not really supported per the discussion [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/2786). The guidance provided [here](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/4653#issuecomment-930420476) suggests:

> It is instead recommended to create all the subnets in the array property inside of the vnet

And unfortunately this suggests that you have to create all the subnets at once to accommodate the API shortcomings. Sorry!